# Ordinal independent variable (IV) and continuous dependent variable (DV)

Tags: regression, interaction, spss, ordinal-data, continuous-data

My independent variable is measured on a likert scale (1–5).

My moderator is dichonomous (yes or no)

I want to use SPSS process macro to measure the moderation relationship. Should I use a dependent variable that can only take values 1,2,3,4,5 (same as IV) or can I use a continuous variable with a range of 10–20?

In case I go with the latter, will my results make sense given that the range of the IV and DV are completely different?

Answer (score 3):

You should use the DV that you want to analyze.

There is no need for the DV and IV to be on the same scales, or have the same range, or anything else like that.

Questions about how to use SPSS (or any program) to do things are off topic here, but I will say that if SPSS can't handle this, get a new program.  (I'd be amazed if that was the case; SPSS isn't my favorite stats program, but this is pretty elementary. However, I know nothing about the process macro).